# NoSuchElementException keeps getting triggered and I'm not sure why

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

Basically what the aim of my program is, is to select a random quote from a text file and print it based on a random number generated that is no bigger than the number of lines in the file. I know the file is in the correct directory and contains all of the content.

I've tried using both while and for loops, but those seem to be the problem the code runs without error when the loops are not in there, but without the loops, the program doesn't do what I want it to do. Also, have tried changing the scope of certain variables.

```
// open file
private static void openFile(){

    try {
        input = new Scanner(Paths.get("Quotes.txt"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

// get and print quote
private static void printQuote(){

    try {
        int printQue = randomNumber();

        System.out.println(printQue);
        for (int i = 0; i < printQue - 1; i++){
            input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.printf("The randomly selected quote is: %s%n", 
        input.nextLine());
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException elementException){
        System.err.println("File formed improperly. Terminating.");
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException stateException){
        System.err.println("Error reading from file. Terminating.");
    }
}

// size of list
private static int fileSize(){

    try{
        int counter = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()){
            input.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }

        num = counter;
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException elementException){
        System.err.println("File improperly formed. Terminating");
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException stateException){
        System.err.println("Error reading from file. Terminating.");
    }

    return num;
}

// get random number
private static int randomNumber(){

    int randomNum = random.nextInt(fileSize());

    while (randomNum <= 0){
        randomNum = random.nextInt(fileSize());
    }

    return randomNum;
}
```

Print one of the 100 quotes in the text file.

Comment: in your printQuote method you are calling input.nextLine() in your printf statement. This iterates through the file which is probably not what you want to do.You should instead only call input.nextLine() once and store the result in a String and use that String later

Answer (score 0):

Your scanner is iterating over the entire file in your fileSize() method because you're calling `input.nextLine()` every iteration.

Once you get to `printQuote()` you have already iterated over the entire file, so you're trying to read in a line at (last_index + 1).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Went back and changed some code and it is running as planned!

Comment: Good to hear. Best of luck.